# How to get a SOQL query to return duplicates?

Tags: apex, soql

Yes i want duplicate records.

Here's the query

```
        /**
    * retrive pbentries for selected products
    * @param selectedProducts
    */
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static list<PricebookEntry> getPriceBookEntryIds(string[] selectedProducts){
        

        PricebookEntry[] pbEntry = [SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry 
                                    WHERE Pricebook2Id =:PRICEBOOK2_ID 
                                    AND Product2Id =:selectedProducts
                                    AND IsActive = TRUE
                                    ];
                  
        return pbEntry;
    }
```

selectedProduct will contain say 6 product2 ids, 2 of which are the same id so the query only returns 5 pricebookentry ids. How would i get it to return 6 pricebook entry ids? One for each value being passed to it?

Where it's getting consumed, in the creation of opportunity line items for a quote. it goes back to an LWC and

```
    createOppLine(){
    let oliArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i<this.priceBookEntry.length; i++){
        let oli = { 'sobjectType' : 'OpportunityLineItem' };
        oli.UnitPrice = 0;
        oli.Quantity = -1;
        oli.Product2Id = this.priceBookEntry[i].Product2Id;
        oli.Quote_Worksheet__c = this.newQuoteLineItem; 
        oli.OpportunityId = this.parentOpp;
        oli.PricebookEntryId = this.priceBookEntry[i].Id;
        oliArray.push(oli);
}
        createOppLineItem({ newOppLine : oliArray});           
}
```

The problem being the user selects 6 products and......then only 5 are saved to the opportunity.

Comment: Where are you consuming this value, that you need a duplicate to be included? Seems like you should instead just return a `Map<Id, PricebookEntryId>`, using `Product2Id` as the key.

Comment: added some context. @AdrianLarson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases don't return duplicate values. This isn't specific to Salesforce, but to any kind of database I've ever seen. If you want to map each price book entry to a product, you do need to map the data afterwards.

As Adrian implied in the comments:

```
@AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
public static Map<Id, PricebookEntry> getPriceBookEntryIds(string[] selectedProducts){
    Map<Id, PricebookEntry> results = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>();
    for(PricebookEntry entry: [SELECT Id, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry 
                                WHERE Pricebook2Id =:PRICEBOOK2_ID 
                                AND Product2Id =:selectedProducts
                                AND IsActive = TRUE
                                ]) 
    {
        results.put(entry.Product2Id, entry);
    }
    return results;
}
```

---

```
let oliArray = this.selectedProducts.map((Product2Id) =>
    ({ 
        sobjectType: 'OpportunityLineItem',
        UnitPrice: 0, 
        Quantity: -1, 
        Product2Id, 
        Quote_Worksheet__c: this.newQuoteLineItem, 
        OpportunityId: this.parentOpp, 
        PricebookEntryId: this.pricebookEntry[Product2Id]
    }));
```